# How do i create my own project in xaamp/htdocs/myworkingfolder/test.php

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I am trying to create my own folder, so i can work with php and try different things out. 
When i try to go to my localhost/testphp/test.php it redirects to a wordpress installation. Why does it do that? It is just a folder with a simple "test.php" 
It then want my database name and so on. It shouldt ask me about those things?
I have allready worked with wordpress before under htdocs where i had to change in the config file in order to connect to the database, but i do not seem to see the need here.

What to do?

Comment: Please show the relevant part of your server configuration and the content of test.php. Are you intending to use Apache? Is a server running? What is the url of your wordpress?

Comment: The test.php contains nothing atm. It is just a empty file.
Appache and mysql is running, I changed the xamp confi to the folder name.
i do not have a url because it is on localhost

Comment: Where is your wordpress project located in comparison to the path of test.php?

Comment: My wordpress projects is located in the htdocs file like test.php

Comment: Do you have a .htaccess file there?

Comment: I do not have a .htacces file there.